# Does the HP Pavilion Dv5 1008TU support additional RAM?

Tags: memory, 64-bit, hp-pavilion

There's not a lot of support anywhere for *this specific model* of PC.

I've sort of converted my HP Pavilion into a server, but as more people begin to use it, it struggles to cope with its 2GB of RAM.

Can I add more RAM (e.g. from 2gb to 8gb) RAM to this computer, and if so, what type does it support?

Comment: 8 GB.See [HP/Compaq Pavilion dv5 Series Notebook dv5-1008tu – RamCity.com.au](https://www.ramcity.com.au/collections/hp-compaq-pavilion-dv5-series-notebook-dv5-1008tu) and https://www.crucial.com

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you very much!